# OpenLayers why are there no features when converting non-zero Selected features to JSON

Tags: openlayers, geojson

Using OpenLayers with a Select interaction to select features, I'm attempting to convert the selected features to JSON for further processing within the `select.on('select', ...)` as per the code below.

```
select.on('select', function() {
     try {
         var json = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures(select.getFeatures(), {});
         console.log(select.getFeatures().getLength());
         console.log(json);
         doStuffWithJSON(json);
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err.message);
     }
});
```

However, the output from the two console.log() lines is:

```
2

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}
```

Ie, there are 2 features selected, but the GeoJSON includes no features.

What am I doing wrong here, and how I can I convert this to correct GeoJSON?

Comment: `select.getFeatures()` returns an OpenLayers collection, `writeFeatures` expects an array of features `select.getFeatures().getArray()`

Comment: @Mike Thank you.  That solved it of course.  RTFM Son_of_a_Beach !!!  :-)  Want to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike commented...

`select.getFeatures()` returns an OpenLayers collection, `writeFeatures()` expects an array of features so:  `select.getFeatures().getArray()`

Fo my code, this now works as expected:

```
select.on('select', function() {
     try {
         var json = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeFeatures(select.getFeatures().getArray(), {});
         console.log(select.getFeatures().getLength());
         console.log(json);
         doStuffWithJSON(json);
     } catch(err) {
         console.log(err.message);
     }
});
```